# RegEx to match only one string divided by a dot

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match only one string where I have some characters or numbers divided by a dot. No more, no less.

Examples:

```
hello.world > OK
five5.eleven11 > OK
john doe > NOT OK
my.name.is.paul > NOT OK
```

I started with this regular expression **`[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]`** but this is not enough because for example *my.name.is.paul* is accepted and shouldn't.

What is the correct regular expression to match what I need ?

Comment: Should the `.`  appear EXACTLY once? Or can it be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the anchor and a quantifier for the last bracket.

```
^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$
```

Comment: Your suggestion works pretty well. Cal you explain me how it works with the final **+** ?

Comment: @Bronzato That's a greedy quantifier for once or more. Since you had it not before you only accepted one character of the bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Use `^\w+\.\w+$`.

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/zvb3J1/1)